# How can I disable checkbox on the grid in ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I need to disable checkbox 'Actions' in the drop-down menu on the grid

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: is 'Actions' column on your grid? Do you want to show or hide that column always?

Comment: @ikettu 'Actions' isn't my custom column (I can't add hideable property), it set on the table by default and I want to ban the user to change the state of the checkbox 'Actions'

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed example? How do you add the 'Actions' column to your grid then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply set the field `hideable` of your **column** to false:

```
columns: [
    {
        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
        text: 'Option'
    }
    {
        xtype: 'actioncolumn',
        text: 'Actions'
        hideable: false, // <<== Here
        hidden: false
    }
]
```

See [hideable](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#cfg-hideable) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Set column as [hideable](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#cfg-hideable) false so that end user can not hide column from UI.